# FindViewById Multiple Times on a Single Line

Tags: java, android, textview, findviewbyid

This is not a problem, but more of an efficiency question. I have multiple TextViews (2 of them) in my XML Layout of my Android App. My question is that can I select multiple TextViews, `findViewById` multiple TextViews on a single line?

Is ***this*** valid for my question?

```
TextView title, darkThemeTitle = findViewById(R.id.title); findViewById(R.id.darkThemeTitle);
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need it in a single line? What is a principal difference of single line rather than multiple?

Comment: Just to minimize the amount of code

Comment: Split code into methods, move findview-code outside of your main code, use folding. I can't understand the advantage of horizontal coding comparing to vertical. Your screen and IDE designed for vertical. What I can practically recommend - use dynamic binding, please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `TextView title, darkThemeTitle = findViewById(R.id.title); findViewById(R.id.darkThemeTitle);` in your code .

- This line `TextView title, darkThemeTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);` will show that **Variable 'title' might not have been initialized** .So `title` **never initialized** in the code .
- And `findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);` will return **View** in your code .And  it never return `darkThemeTitle` in your code .

And  you can do like this .

```
 TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title); TextView darkThemeTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.darkThemeTitle);
```

**Another way**

```
TextView title = null, darkThemeTitle = null;

TextView[] textViews = {title, darkThemeTitle};
Integer[] ids = {R.id.title, R.id.darkThemeTitle};

for (int i = 0; i < textViews.length; i++) {
    textViews[i] = (TextView) findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only recommendation is to use template ids to find views:

```
TextView[] themedViews = new int[NUMBER_OF_THEMES];
for (int k = 0; k < NUMBER_OF_THEMES; k++)
    themedViews[k] = findViewById(context.getResources().getIdentifier("some_prefix" + String.valueOf(k), "id", packageName));
```

This will find all views for current activity.

Or you can use `parent.findViewById` to find subviews of a specified view.

Comment: So this would instantiate all the Views in the XML layout?

Comment: I updated an answer, my previous code was to only find ids of views, I changed it to find views,

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend to use this for find themed controls. Best solution: move your findViewById commands to separated method in helper class.

Answer (score 1):

I discourage you from doing this because it's more difficult for other programmers to read and doesn't save you much time typing.  Use:

```
TextView title = findViewById(R.id.title), darkThemeTitle = findViewById(R.id.darkThemeTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ButterKnife? This library help you with Dependency Injection so you don't need to worry about the `findViewById`. Just call the `@BindView(view_id)` and the type and name of the variable that you want to bind.

```
@BindView(R.id.title)
TextView title;
@BindView(R.id.darkThemeTitle)
TextView darkThemeTitle;
```

Remember that you need to add the dependency in your `build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
```

And call the bind method in the `onCreate` of your activity

```
ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to cast the Views like this ? `TextView title, darkThemeTitle = findViewById(R.id.title); findViewById(R.id.darkThemeTitle);`

Comment: Wouldn't the `ButterKnife.bind(this)` go after all the controls are instantiated?

Comment: If you are using the `ButterKife.bind()` within an `Activity` you can use in the `onCreate` if this is more complex like a `ViewHolder` or `Fragment` you need to use `ButterKnife(this, parentView/activityInstance)`. By `parentView` you can inflate a new layout or pass the `activityInstance`.